# All Integers have the same value

Tags: c

So I am working on some homework, in which I have to create a global array of 500 random integers between 0 and 99. Then, I have to count how many are greater than 75, and how many are less than 50.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int ARRAY[500];
static char str[1];

void main() {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        int r = rand() % 99;
        ARRAY[i] = r;
        }
    int gt75 = count75();
    int lt50 = count50();
    printf("%d\n", str, gt75);
    printf("%d\n", str, lt50);
    }

int count75() {
    int i = 0, counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        int n = ARRAY[i];
        if (n > 75) {
            counter += 1;
            }
        }
    return counter;
    }

int count50() {
    int i = 0, counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 500; i ++) {
        int n = ARRAY[i];
        if (n < 50) {
            counter += 1;
            }
        }
    return counter;
    }
```

However, after compiling and running my program, I get the following output:

```
4225008
4225008
```

This can't be right, as the list should only have 500 elements in the first place. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you must use `srand()` to generate "decent" random numbers http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/

Comment: `printf("%d\n", str, gt75)`; what is `str` doing here?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm not sure, I looked up how to print an integer and that's what a few of the methods used:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732402/how-to-properly-printf-integer-and-string-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two errors.

First, `int r = rand() % 99;` should be `int r = rand() % 100;`  Otherwise you just get numbers between 0 and 98.

Second, your printf statements are odd.  They should be:

```
printf("Greater than 75: %d\n", gt75);
printf("Less than 50: %d\n", lt50);
```

In the current printf statements, the str is cast to an int, which is interpreting the str pointer as an int, thus your strange output.

Answer (score 4):

You're printing a char array with `printf` using `"%d"`, which is for printing integers. Use `"%s"` for printing char arrays:

```
 printf("%s\n", str, gt75);
```

Or, if you're trying to print the value of `gt75` as an integer:

```
printf("%d\n", gt75);
```

I do not know why you would pass `str` in this case, though.

When you use `"%d"`, you are telling `printf` to interpret the input as an `int`. Since `str` is actually a char array, it does not output correctly. Instead, you're printing the memory location of `str`, which is the value of an array.

Comment: Then why is `str` the argument immediately after your format string?

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND str is not an integer. Even its content looks like an integer, the type of str is char[] and therefore you must use %s to print it.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND Exactly what "integer" are you trying to print? if you're trying to print the value of `gt75`, pass that to printf right after your format string without `str` in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

You are always printing the value of `str`, which is not an `int`.