# How to print a character but by using variable?

Tags: c

Simple example for my problem:

```
char answer;

printf("enter your favorite letter: \n");

answer = getchar();
```

Now here is the problem. I want to print that character in screen. But by using "answer" variable.
Something like this:

```
printf(answer);
```

But of course it doesn't work. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just after the command to print a char to the console?

```
int main() {
    char answer;

    printf("enter your favorite letter: \n");

    answer = getchar();

    printf("%c\n", answer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `printf`. This lets you 'embed' variables in output using placeholders declared with `%` prefixes.

The placeholder for a character is `%c`, so you could use the following:

```
printf("Your favorite letter is %c", answer);
```

`answer` is passed as a parameter and replaces the `%c`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732402/how-to-properly-printf-integer-and-string-in-c) should give you more information about `printf`.

Comment: @blackwater7 No problem!